# Confluent-hub failed to download plugins 'Component not found'

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using kafka/kafka-connect via confluent platform helm-chart ([here](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts)).

For Kafka-Connect I want to install both debezium SQLServer source connector and BQ sink connector, the only way I found it with the current setup is to update the `template/deployment.yaml` to add an `initContainers` section to download the plugins using `confluent-hub` CLI.

The problem is, the `confluent-hub` command is inconsistent, sometimes download the plugins and sometimes not, and when asked on confluent community on slack, I found others face the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I implemented for such case is to retry during the `initContainer` script till the plugin is downloaded using the following script -it assumes that confluent-hub is just the `bin` directory away, and the connector config file under the path of `--worker-configs`-.

For those who don't know what does the `$?` do, it holds the response code of the last ran command, which is in our case is the `./bin/confluent-hub install...` command. ([more details](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-shell-command-exit-codes))

```
./bin/confluent-hub install wepay/kafka-connect-bigquery:2.4.2 --component-dir bqkc  --worker-configs /etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties --no-prompt
while [ $? -eq 1 ]
do
    echo "Failed to download the connector, will sleep and retry again"
    sleep 10
    ./bin/confluent-hub install wepay/kafka-connect-bigquery:2.4.2 --component-dir bqkc  --worker-configs /etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties --no-prompt
done
```

Comment: This could be simplified with a function rather than copying the same command twice